# ol bullet types and text css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an ol with this css:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  color: red;
}
```

My question is this...my li and any text within will be red.

```
<li>Some Text</li>
```

if I do:

```
<li><span>Some Text</span></li>
```

Its no problem I can manipulate span as I wish,
But...
is there a css way to alter the text color without encompassing in a separate element?

Your advice is appreciated :)

Comment: `li {color:blue}`?

Comment: The question you've link is for ul....I'm using an ol with list-style-type and said solution do not yield the desired result.

Comment: You haven't really explained what your desired result is and have not replied to my comment - if you are only wanting to change the text colour and not the roman numerals too then no there is no other way than to wrap the text in another element

Comment: thank you that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: if it were normal numbers and not roman numerals, you could use a pseduo element and css counters

Comment: @Pete please consider removing your duplicate flag.
And see the answer I marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `counters` like following

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style: none;
}

li::before {
  color: red;
  content: counter(section, upper-roman);
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li {
  counter-increment: section;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @AviE.Koenig - Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use various psuedo selectors to target different LI's specifically, such as, either based on numerical order, order rules or specifically if they are first or last.

```
// Target the 2nd list item
ol li:nth-child(2) {
color: blue;
}

// Target every 3rd item and the 1st item
ol li:nth-child(3n+1) {
color: blue;
}

// Target only the first list item
ol li:first-child {
color: green;
}

// Target only the last list item
ol li:last-child {
color: purple;
}
```